# How to make the bars in histogram panel clickable - kibana ES

Tags: javascript, angularjs, elasticsearch, kibana

I would like to make the bars in histogram panel of kibana clickable. Similar to terms panel, where on clicking on a term will refresh the dashboards with relevant values, I want the histogram panel to be clickable. I went through module.js and module.html in histogram panel folder. The $scope.panel has the values for filter to be st. But i am unable to figure out how to make the bar clickable. Kindly help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The histogram graph is using the http://www.flotcharts.org/ library. You will want to familiarize yourself with it in order to make the change that you describe.

HEre is the code in Kibana that instantiates the histogram graph:
https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/blob/master/src/app/panels/histogram/module.js#L742

```
plot = $.plot(elem, data, options);
```

This tutorial shows how the interaction works with a flot chart: http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/interacting/index.html

You will need to bind your action on click on the chart in the following way:

```
    $("#histogram-chart").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {
        if (item) {
            $("#clickdata").text(" - click point " + item.dataIndex + " in " + item.series.label);
            plot.highlight(item.series, item.datapoint);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Including the action on click in https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/blob/master/src/app/panels/histogram/module.js does not work. The action was not triggered. On analysing,
https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/blob/master/src/app/panels/histogram/module.js#L673 had hoverable property set to true. I found that a property called clickable has to be set true. Now its working. Thanks for your lead.

Comment: Hi @Hari, Do you know if there is an enhancement request created for this in kibana. I dont see this feature with the latest source code checked out.